# Doubts on how to create C dll to be called from Lua code. Something wrong with syntax of typedef (pointer to function that returns const char *)

Tags: c, dll, lua, function-pointers, dllimport

(I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional)

Firstly, I'd like to know if this is the correct way to import functions from C dlls: creating a pointer to them and assigning the value of such pointer via `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. I'm trying it like this because I can't properly build my C code and call it from Lua interactive console. This was a desperate attempt. And yet, I got these errors that I'd like to understand.

Secondly, I don't know how to correct this warning:
`C4090: 'function' different 'const' qualifiers`

This is a shortened version of the dll I'm trying to compile.

```
//stdafx.h
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef const char * ( CALLBACK* luafnptr_typename ) ( lua_State *L, int tp );
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And this code file:

```
//dllmain.c
#include "stdafx.h"

HINSTANCE hDLL;
luafnptr_typename l_typename = NULL;

BOOL load ( );
BOOL unload ( );


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        return load ( );
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        return unload ( );
        break;
    }
}

BOOL load ( )
{
    hDLL = LoadLibrary ( "C:/Lua/5.2.4/lua5.2.4.dll" );
    if ( hDLL != NULL )
    {
        l_typename = ( luafnptr_typename ) GetProcAddress ( hDLL, "lua_typename" );
        if ( !l_typename )
        {
            FreeLibrary ( hDLL );
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL unload ( )
{
    free ( l_typename );// <<< THIS LINE REPORTS THE WARNING
    l_typename = NULL;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Lastly, I also get a lot of `LNK2001 unresolved external symbol [X]` and `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol [X] referenced in function [Y]`

For example:

`LNK2001    unresolved external symbol _floor LuaExperiment C:\Users\Kauan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\LuaExperiment\LuaExperiment\lua5.2.4-static.lib(lvm.obj)`

and:

`LNK2019    unresolved external symbol _floor referenced in function _luaO_arith    LuaExperiment C:\Users\Kauan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\LuaExperiment\LuaExperiment\lua5.2.4-static.lib(lobject.obj)`

I added Lua to the project simply by going to `Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Aditional Dependencies->Edit...` and added the value `C:\Lua\5.2.4\*.lib` nothing else.

Comment: Even if you make it compile you are breaking the rules by calling LoadLibrary from DllMain. You will have to stop that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you very much! I had no idea. This was a desperate attempt, because I couldn't run the dll from inside Lua. Do you have ant suggestions?

Comment: No idea why you would create a dll just to load a function from another dll. What is your actual problem.

Comment: I want to write a C lib to be called from inside Lua code. I had problems with linking, so I decided to forcefully grab the function pointers by name, since Lua is written in C, thus preserving the function names. As mentioned, the only thing I did to link Lua to my code was to add the folder where I compiled it and created its libraries to the Linker's input.

Comment: Sorry makes little sense to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's ok. Thank you for all your help.